# Probability Measure over sentences of ZFC

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous Strictly Positive Measures on Countable Boolean Algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100724/continuous-strictly-positive-measures-on-countable-boolean-algebras)

Let B be the Boolean Algebra of sentences in the language of set theory modulo provable equivalence in ZFC. That is to say, for each sentence $\sigma$ in the language of set theory, let $[\sigma]$ be the set of sentences in the language of set theory provably equivalent to $\sigma$. The set of equivalence classes $[\sigma]$ under the obvious operations is the Boolean Algebra in which we are interested.

Is it possible for there to be a countably additive probability measure $\mu$ on $B$ such that $\mu$ assigns every non-zero element of $B$ strictly positive probability? Must there be such a probability measure $\mu$? (Note: I added the condition of countable additivity when some commenters correctly pointed out that every countable Boolean algebra admits a strictly positive probability measure.)

Comment: Is this close to what you want - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99808/strictly-positive-measures-on-countable-boolean-algebras


Comment: By the way, Dana Scott's latest work is about probabilistic models of set theory. It might be relevant to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand Qiaochu's comment.  Yes, the (Lindenbaum-Tarski) algebra of sentences in the language of set theory modulo equivalence in ZFC is countable and therefore supports a strictly positive probability measure.  But there are uncountable Boolean algebras with such a measure, the prime example being the measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ modulo the measure 0 sets.

Comment: To Dorais and Qioachu  - I suppose I should have made it more explicit, but I want it to be a countably additive probability measure. I don't think every countable Boolean algebra necessarily supports a countably additive, strictly positive countable measure. But it is my fault for not making this condition clear.

Comment: Then the answer is no, there is no countably additive measure on the atomless countable Boolean algebra, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100724 .

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Stefan: my apologies. I was under the mistaken impression that the OP wanted a measure on $B$ as a _set_. 

Comment: I closed as duplicate, otherwise it will keep popping up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

This Boolean algebra is atomless (assuming ZFC is consistent).
Namely, let $\varphi$ be a sentence whose equivalence class is $\not=0$.
Then ZFC+$\varphi$ is consistent.  By the incompleteness theorem, ZFC+$\varphi$+$\neg$Con(ZFC+$\varphi$) is consistent as well.
It follows that the equivalence classes of $\varphi\wedge\neg\mbox{Con(ZFC}+\varphi$) and
$\varphi\wedge\mbox{Con(ZFC}+\varphi$) are both below the one of $\varphi$ and both positive.

Luckily, there is just one countable atomless Boolean algebra, namely the algebra of clopen subsets of the Cantor space ($2^\omega$).
This algebra sits inside the measure algebra of the Cantor space (with the product measure coming from the measure that assigns $1/2$ to the singletons $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$).
So there is your countably additive measure (countably additive with respect to sums that actually exist in the Boolean algebra).

Edit:  As Emil Jerabek points out, this is actually not the case.  The problem is that the countable BA is not a complete subalgebra of the measure algebra, i.e., there are infinite
subsets of the countable BA that have a sup in the countable BA but that sup does not agree with the sup taken in the big measure algebra.

So, it seems this argument only gives a finitely additive measure on this BA.

Comment: This answer is wrong, as the embedding of the algebra in the measure algebra on the Cantor space does not preserve existing countable joins and meets. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100724.